# How do I store changes of last run

Tags: java, android, local-storage, storage

I have created this application in which when a button is pressed, instances of an activity are created. In these instances, I dynamically add views(Editviews).

Now, my query is How do I store these instances of activity including all the views added in it, so that in my next run, these instances are restored same as they were left in last run.

Comment: You can store the data that is bound to the views and recreate the views. There's no reason to store the view themselves

Comment: Saving the view themselves is a bad idea. And i would not be surprised if it was impossible due to the lifecycle events. Instead you should save whatever data you need to recreate them ([savedInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#lc) is usefull for that) and then recreate the views

Comment: I got more than 10 instances of that activity & each of those has different views in it. All this is created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there are parameters based off which the views are generated, and added to your application.

Every time a view is added, you could add these parameters to a database, or a flat file and persist it.

Note: By view I am referring to whatever data you intend to restore on next start up of the application.

When you launch the application next time, you could:

- either restore all automatically,
  OR
- give a button clicking which restores all views from previous session,
  OR
- give an option to show list of earlier views, and allow user to select the ones he wants.

Comment: I want to restore all the instances as well as views in it, automatically. How do i implement it in Code?